# How to use String for case label within switch statement

Tags: java, android, firebase, switch-statement

I am trying to figure out how to put a string into a case label in this switch statement so it will work in other languages as well. Here is my code currently.

Or if there is a better way to code this so when other languages are used the button will still work

```
if (profileid.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
        edit_profile.setText(R.string.edit_Profile_Button);
    } else {
        checkFollow();
        saved_photos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        my_photos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    edit_profile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String btn = edit_profile.getText().toString();
        switch (btn) {
            case "Edit Profile":
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), EditProfileActivity.class));
                break;
            case "support":
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Support").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("supporting").child(profileid).setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Support").child(profileid)
                        .child("supporters").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addNotifications();
                break;
            case "supporting":
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Support").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("supporting").child(profileid).removeValue();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Support").child(profileid)
                        .child("supporters").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.properties` file to store the labels in different languages against a key i.e. the key will remain the same for each language but the value will be specific to the language e.g. the name of your properties file for English is  `myapps_en.properties` and that for German is `myapps_en.properties`. In both the files, the keys will be same but the values will be specific to the language.

Now, you can use the keys (instead of values) in the `case`.

You can check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/learn-how-to-internationalize-and-localize-your-ja) for an example of how localization works using `.properties` files.

Comment: could i just add another case for the text in another language? it seemed to work when i did that

Comment: Of course, it will work but imagine you have `10` languages to deal with and there are `5` cases for each language. In that situation, you will have `50` `case` blocks. Just imagine how unmanageable your code would be with that kind of implementation.